# Postgres database migrations with vault

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration, hashicorp-vault

I am currently using vault to generate database credentials.
The service itself handles migrations against the database.
I end up with tables owned by the generated vault role. the database administrator loses access to these tables and is not able to generate a new user against the same set of tables. 
Any tips or ideas on how to solve this in a good way?

Comment: What is vault? That tool from HashiCorp states PostgreSQL support as deprecated. How can administrator lose access to anything in database (not superuser?)? What are you trying to do (like does it have to be done using this "vault")?

Comment: The postgreSQL secrets engine is deprecated but not support for postgres, it has been moved to the database engine. 
As for the access it had to do with ownership of the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to create a trigger on create table to alter the table owner to a shared admin group.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html